# hideKeyboard method in class in android

Tags: java, android

```
private void hideKeyboard() {
    try {
        // Close Soft Keyboard
        InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)
                mContext.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

        inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(rootView.getWindowToken(),
                InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
    } catch (Exception keyboardHideExp) {
        Log.d("eEmp/HideKbExp", "Exception raised due to " + keyboardHideExp.toString());
    }
}
```

This was used in `fragment`. I need to use same method in my `class` but giving error at `rootView`. How can I access in my `class`.

> inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(rootView.getWindowToken(),
>                       InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);

I am new to android.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: in which class are u accessing hideKeyboard

Comment: Do you want to hide keyBoard on any action?

Comment: getView() should work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need parent `View`. How your method is getting `rootView` variable?
The simplest way is:

In *YourClass.class*

```
public void closeKeyboard(Context context, View view) {
   InputMethodManager inputMethodManager =(InputMethodManager)context.getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
   inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getWindowToken(), 0);
}
```

Or instead of `view.getWindowToken()` use `context.getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken()`.

In *YourActivity.class*

```
EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.my_edit_text);
new YourClass().closeKeyboard(this, editText);
```

The EditText should be in activity/fragment layout.

Comment: giving error at view@EJusius

Comment: Is a view in your fragment and did you find it by id before setting there? @kalyan

Comment: even though giving error at getCurrentFocuss()@EJusius

Comment: do I need to create view variable in my class? @EJusius

Comment: You need to get it from your fragment or activity layout @kalyan

Comment: `View` is superclass of for example `EditText`, `Button`, `TextView` an other widgets... @kalyan

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.

```
Context mcontext;
View rootView;
classConstructor(Context context, View view){
this.mcontext = context;
this.rootView = view;
}
private void hideKeyboard()
{
try {
// Close Soft Keyboard
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)
                mContext.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(rootView.getWindowToken(),
                InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
} catch (Exception keyboardHideExp) {
        Log.d("eEmp/HideKbExp", "Exception raised due to " + keyboardHideExp.toString());
}
}
```

Comment: In this lines this.mcontext = context;
this.rootView = view; 
Do we need this?

Comment: This depends on how are you doing.

Comment: if we have 
this.context = context;
this.view = view;

then we need this but for different names we dont need this.

in this case we can specify it as-:

mcontext = context;
rootView = view;

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as you using `Fragment`.

```
private void hideKeyBoard() {
    if (getActivity().getCurrentFocus() != null) {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getActivity().getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
}
```

It's works for me...